# is any windows application available for accelerometer based computer mouse

Tags: arduino-uno, accelerometer

I want to make an AIR mouse using Arduino
and accelerometer, for this i used USB to TTL
converter i have done everything successfully
but can anyone tell me how use it in computer.
I mean i don't know how to make computer
application for this mouse. please suggest me
any application for this. And give any idea for
"how can i use Bluetooth for this."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

......................................
......................................